# Yii2 'Your system does not support any of these drivers: gmagick,imagick,gd2'

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, imagick, gd2, gmagick

The problem is like this : i am following a yii tutorial in order to learn more about the framework, the tutorial is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whuIf33v2Ug&t=11365s and i found myself strugalling at 2:55:31 ( thumbnail resize ) , i installed the necesary dependencie using `composer require yiisoft/yii2-imagine` and i wrote the code.

```
 Image::getImagine()
                ->open($thumbnailPath)
                ->thumbnail(new Box(1280, 1280))
                ->save();
```

but for some reason i encountered this error and i can't figure out how to resolve it :

"Your system does not support any of these drivers: gmagick,imagick,gd2"

[image of the error in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vzRS.png)

Comment: Install the driver with php.

Answer (score 0):

that one is not a yii2 error. you will need to enable one of that extension in you php.ini

if you are a windows user:

i would suggest to start with gd2 that one does not need any extra installation, only you will need to uncomment following line in your php.ini

extension=gd2

if you are linux user:

```
sudo apt-get install php-gd
```

will solve your problem. (you will need root permissions to the system)